# full calendar obtener una fecha en un input inmediatamente le de click al dia

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(event, jsEvent, view) {
   $('#DivPrincipal').load('calendario_reservaciones.php',function() {
     $( '#calendar' ).css( 'display', 'block' );
     $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
     weekends: true,
     dayClick: function() {
     $("#mtitulo").html(event.title);
     $("#modal_reservacion").modal();

  },

  eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $("#mtitulo").html(event.title); 
    console.log(event.start._i);
    console.log(jsEvent);
    console.log(view);
    $("#mfecha_ini").val(event.start._i); 
    $("#model_reservacion_Editar").modal();



  },

  header:{
    left:   ' today ', 
    center: 'title Cancha1',
    right:  ' month,agendaWeek,agendaDay prev,next'
  },
  lang: 'es',
  footer: {
    right: ' month,agendaWeek,agendaDay prev,next'
  },
  customButtons: {
    Cancha1: {
      text: 'Cancha1',
      click: function() {
        alert('clicked the custom button!');
      }
    },



  },


  firstDay:0,
  eventLimit : 2,
            // weekNumbers: true,
            // content Height: 600
             // aspectRatio: 1
             eventSources: [

          // your event source
          {
              url: '../controladores/reservaciones.php ', // use the `url` property
              color: '#0a48b5',    // an option!
              textColor: 'white',
              editable: true,
              eventlimit:true,
              eventStartEditable : true,
              eventlimit: true,
                  // an option!
                }

                ],
                defaultTimedEventDuration:"01:00:00",
                selectable:true
              });
```

este es mi js no tengo idea como llamar esa fecha

```
<div class = "form-group row">
<label for = "hora_final" class = "col-sm-2 control-label"> Fecha de Reservacion </label>
<div class = "col-sm-10" >
<input id="fecha_reser" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha Reservacion" name="fecha_reser" >
```

esta es una parte de mi ventana modal quiero que esa fecha se imprima  en #fecha_reser

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor tu problema? No se termina de entender bien.

Comment: gracias ayer resolvi mi problema era que cuando le daba a mi calendario abria mi ventana modal y tenia que cargar en mi input de la ventana modal la fecha que eleji en mi calendario

Comment: dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $("#fecha_reser").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));

Comment: añado el codigo por si alguien mas lo necesita gracias